Write DuckDB csv to Python string
I have a DuckDBPyRelation and I'd like to get it as a csv
For example, if I have
import polars as pl
import duckdb

data = pl.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})
rel = duckdb.sql('select * from data')

then I'd like to do something like
out = rel.to_csv()

However, DuckDB doesn't support this, you can only pass a file name to to_csv
I'd like to end up with
>>> out
'a\n1\n2\n3\n'

What would be the most efficient way to do this, without converting to other Python libraries like pandas / Polars / PyArrow?
All I can think of is to write to a temporary file, then read that with Python

It seems you can reach this with export the database.

how?............

Not an answer, but the closest I could find was someone using fsspec to write to memory://filename https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/discussions/11499

does the following satisfy your requirement?
cat test.py 
import polars as pl
import duckdb
data = pl.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,]})
duckdb.sql("COPY (select * from data) to 'test.csv'")
$ python test.py
$ cat test.csv 
a
1
2
3


### option 2
con = duckdb.connect()
data = pl.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,]})
con.execute("select * from data").fetchall()
[(1,), (2,), (3,)]
"\n".join([", ".join(map(str, record)) for record in con.execute("select * from data").fetchall()])
'1\n2\n3'


no, I need to get it as a Python string. This is no different to writing to a temporary csv and then reading it in Python

ok. what's the relevance of polars and csv in your request ? - neither appear to be relevant. , i'll given another offering
